# How to check which log file is latest one in KUDU?

Tags: azure

In Azure KUDU, we have more number of log files and it is difficult to find which one is latest one and which one currently updating.

Is there any way to see the latest file? We don't want cleanup the files to see the latest one always.

Comment: If you web app is hosted on windows app service plan then you can run the below cmdlet using PowerShell based debug console (locate to the logfile path) in your kudu console to find the latest log file and also last write time as well. 
`Get-ChildItem | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) }`

Comment: It is web app service. I have tried this command, but it is not returning any results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @[shelladmin](https://shellgeek.com/powershell-get-last-modified-file-in-the-directory/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20latest%20file%20in%20the%20directory%20using%20PowerShell,file%20created%20in%20the%20directory.) for the PowerShell command.

I have observed that the logs are displaying in ascending order.
So, the latest file will be at last.

Open the `KUDU Console` and Navigate to the path where your log files reside.

Here Iam trying to sort the log files in `C:\home\LogFiles\kudu\trace` folder.

[image]

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\home\LogFiles\kudu\trace" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending
```

***Output without filter:***

[image]

If you want to filter the files with any extension, then use the below command.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\home\LogFiles\kudu\trace" -Filter "*.xml" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending
```

***Output with filter:***

[image]

Replace the path with your folder path.